# Where to Put MVVM CustomControl ViewModels/Classes WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, custom-controls, code-organization

I am currently working in MVVM and have created a xaml "TargetType" class for my custom-styled searchTextBox control.

Problem is, I am wondering how where to put these files/what to call the folder so my project remains neat and tidy. I strictly abide by [this group's Project Structure](http://projekt202.com/blog/2010/xaml-organization/) for ResourceDictionary organization, but I'd like to see an outline with some example files based on what other teams are doing with their CustomControl classes. Do they refer to them as ViewModels? Are they in a separate ControlLibrary? etc.

Does anyone have any easy-reading resources? I really haven't found what I'm looking for, suprisingly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use MVVM strictly, your custom controls can't be a part of main ViewModels. That's why you have to separate them in a (Control)Library and add to your project as a reference. *(The main goal of MVVM: Graphics experts can work on the frontend layer(in this case view using xaml) independently meanwhile programmers can work on the backend layer(in this case model). And Programmers can create a connection between these layers (viewmodel). That's why strict MVVM doesn't allow code-behind.)* So back to your question, "Are they in a separate ControlLibrary?" -Yes, it can be a solution. But there's the most important thing:
If you place custom elements in a control library you can SHARE your work with multiple WPF applications(easily).

There's a book: [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-2010-Presentation-Foundation/dp/1430272058](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272058)
What you need is in Chapter 18 - Custom Elements. There's a long 'explain' why you should use control library and what about special cases etc... (sorry for my english)

Comment: Thanks very much. Your English was perfect, actually. I'll check out the resource. After thinking about this after I asked it, there really seems to be no other solution. I would however like to see some much larger projects organized somewhere, so hopefully I can find a resource somewhere like that. I'm just very meticulous with folder organization.